# Possible to style jsoup output with CSS?

Tags: java, android, html, css, jsoup

I successfully retrieved specific text from a website with Jsoup. But is it possible to style the text with CSS? Below you find my code for retrieving text from a website.

```js
 public class connect extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        String string;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                Document document = Jsoup.connect("MY_URL").get();
                Elements elements = document.select("div.MY_DIV_CLASS");
                string = elements.text();


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            webView.loadData(string, "text/html", "UTF-8");

        }
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have selected element or elements you can style it by adding new class:

```
    elements.addClass("your-class");
```

or by adding your own style attribute:

```
    elements.attr("style", "text-align: center; color: red;");
```

These changes are saved in `document` object so to use updated HTML code you will probably want to use the output of: `document.html()`.

Comment: Thank you. It's working flawless. I added my own style attribute and used the output of document.html().